# Laravel 10 keeps logging me off

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-10

I have a Laravel 10 application which uses Laravel Breeze. The problem is that sometimes my website is logging me off after performing few requests (clicks in the menu). Sometimes it works fine but after a while it is broken without any changes. In the console a have found the problem is thrown by auth middleware and I am receiving this message:

```
Unauthenticated.
/my-project-pah/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php#96
```

I thought the problem is with RateLimiter, but there is none set in my code.
I have tried Safari and Chrome, but the problem occurs all the same.

I tried to edit session config and check application config for some request limit. After removing all session data it was fine for a while but the problem occurred later.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Yes I have this problem but very rarely, in my case the cache (which I use for sessions as well) seems to get flushed by some unknown process (meaning I put in there it at some point but then I forgot where and why). You can check if this is the issue for you by changing session drivers to something different than what you use for the cache (if they are the same) e.g. file or database if you are using redis

Comment: Unfortunately I am already using file driver for cache and database (NoSQL locally) for the session. Maybe I will try MySQL database which is supposed to be used in production.